# Elastic Beanstalk: How can my team deploy code to the same environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was previously on Google App Engine and have migrated to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. My team and I are working together on a website, but only I have managed to deploy code from my own computer.

How would my team go about deploying the code to the environment from their own computers? They have installed the eb command line tool.

Comment: Your statement "only I have managed to deploy code from my own computer" makes it sound like the other users have tried but encountered some sort of error or problem? What exactly is the problem? Did each user successfully run `eb init` to configure the eb command line tool?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. No they haven't tried it. We aren't sure how we should approach this. If my teammates run `eb init`, wouldn't it create a new environment? We want to work on and deploy code to an existing environment I created with `eb init`.

Answer (score 0):

They need to install EB CLI on their computer. Once EB CLI is install they can run "eb deploy" command. More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html).

Comment: I understand they can run `eb deploy`, but it doesn't deploy to an existing environment I created. It would deploy to a new environment they created with `eb init`. I have gone through the documentation, but I may have overlooked this specific portion. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Run `eb init` and `eb create` on one machine so that the environment is up and running.

On all machines you need setup .elasticbeanstalk and ..ebextensions folders, add them to git for example.

Run `aws configure` on each machine. The profile name in .elasticbeanstalk/config needs to match to the credentials in ~/.aws/config

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Don't forget to add permissions to your users. You can start with power user permission, but you should create a more specific role/policy for this later.

When this is setup all your users should be able to `eb deploy`.